# Univerzal class setter - Java

Tags: java

Since I have a class with 8 parameters (p1,p2,...), all of type boolean, I was wondering if it is possible to create a setter method that has **two parameters**: object's **variable member**(to determine which of p1,p2,... to set) and a **value**, instead of creating 8 different setters).

Let's say we have following class:

```
public class SomeClass{

    private boolean p1;
    private boolean p2;
    private boolean p3;
    private boolean p4;
    private boolean p5;
    private boolean p6;
    private boolean p7;
    private boolean p8;
}
```

How is it possible to create an **univerzal setter** for any of those p1-p8 ? Something like:

```
public void setP(SomeClass.param p, boolean value)
```

Comment: You could use the Reflection API but I strongly advise against doing such a thing. There is nothing wrong with creating a setter for each field.

Comment: Have you considered using a BitSet? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html. Might not be a good idea to bundle them together, but one getter/setter might make sense if p1-p8 shouldn't really be separate parameters.

Comment: maybe class is bad designed. If all have similar real-life nature, maybe better be array?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I've solved the problem by deleting the class and just creating a map instead, where key represents parameter and value represents boolean value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has found a solution himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeanUtils` from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)

```
void setP(String name, Boolean value) {
    BeanUtils.setProperty(this, name, value);
}
```

or using an int

```
void setP(Integer i, Boolean value) {
    BeanUtils.setProperty(this, "p"+i.toString(), value);
}
```

generally speaking it works, but be aware it is not totally safe, since both name or i can assume illegal values and you should better add a some sanity check, otherwise you can get an `IllegalAccessException` or an `InvocationTargetException`. 
The advantage of using the 8 setter is of course compile time checking, and your ide can write them for you.
And of course, as suggested, this library is using reflection.